# xcode server bot archive export method

Tags: ios, xcode, server, archive

When my xcode server archives and creates a user-installable product, it doesn't automatically choose an enterprise cert. It exports using a developer cert which means the resulting ipa cannot be distributed to my company. When exporting via command line, you can specify an export options plist with the export method specified there.

Can I specify the export method or export options plist so that I don't have to make a post-integration trigger?

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't an easy way to do this in Xcode 8, but starting with Xcode 9 you can specify an export options plist.